# Как создать собственные ID для mongoose?

Tags: mongoose

Я знаю, что mongoose автоматически создает id, но вид у них не привлекательный (60ad13d1e654db159c054a05), как задать собственные id (вида 1,2,3,4 ) и чтобы они сами увеличивались на один при создании записи?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28357965/mongoose-auto-increment

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-sequence